# Controlling Nest from Firebase

Tags: firebase, integration, nest-api

Since Google owns Nest is there a viable way to control / interact with your camera via Firebase? I'm trying to integrate my Nest camera just by using the URL provided. Although, it would be nice to use some sort of API or service within Firebase.

I can use the shareable link provided from Nest to view the camera feed within my Flutter App.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't provide any APIs to interact with Nest devices.  If there are any APIs, they would be provided by Nest.  If you want to use them in conjunction with Firebase, then that's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

See this post:  [Nest Camera API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014659/nest-camera-api)

The old API is now deprecated, replaced by the new one, Smart Device Management API.