# Nest Camera API

Tags: python, php, nest-api

Anyone tried creating a third party app for Nest for migrated accounts to Google? Looks like they aren't releasing the API anymore for migrated accounts and was discontinued.

I'm currently working on a security app that involves the Nest cameras which shows realtime status of

- Camera Status (Online/Offline)
- Someone is detected by Nest camera

I tried searching for an API to work on this and haven't seen a working API for migrated accounts. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Thanks,

Comment: Please use the search function first:
[Results for: nest camera api](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nest+camera+api)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API to control a NEST camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060129/api-to-control-a-nest-camera)

Answer (score 0):

After migrating to the google account, you need to participate in their Device Access program to consume their new API (Smart Device Management API). Follow these instructions: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/get-started

Once you've got that all set up, you can tap into the Nest camera traits for what you are after:  https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-person

Good luck!